# impl convert::From for (mutable) reference

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to implement `From` for a type I want to get as a mutable reference, so I impl it for a `&mut TheType`, but then how do I properly call `from`? Attempts I performed fail because it tries to do reflexion (TheType from TheType) or can't (or don't know how to) call `from` from a type `&mut TheType`.

Code will explain it better hopefully:

```
enum Component {
    Position(Point),
    //other stuff
}

struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl<'a> std::convert::From<&'a mut Component> for &'a mut Point {
    fn from(comp: &'a mut Component) -> &mut Point {
        // If let or match for Components that can contain Points
        if let &mut Component::Position(ref mut point) = comp {
            point
        } else { panic!("Cannot make a Point out of this component!"); }
    }
}

// Some function somewhere where I know for a fact that the component passed can contain a Point. And I need to modify the contained Point. I could do if let or match here, but that would easily bloat my code since there's a few other Components I want to implement similar Froms and several functions like this one. 
fn foo(..., component: &mut Component) {
    // Error: Tries to do a reflexive From, expecting a Point, not a Component
    // Meaning it is trying to make a regular point, and then grab a mutable ref out of it, right?
    let component = &mut Point::from(component)

    // I try to do this, but seems like this is not a thing.
    let component = (&mut Point)::from(component) // Error: unexpected ':'

    ...
}
```

Is what I'm trying to do here possible? The `impl From` above compiles just fine, is just the calling of it that escapes me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do this would be to specify the type of `component` like this:

```
let component: &mut Point = From::from(component);
```

As [Simon Whitehead](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1517578/simon-whitehead) pointed out, the more idiomatic way to do this would be to use the corresponding function [`into()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html):

```
let component: &mut Point = component.into();
```

Comment: Also, because the stdlib includes many variations of `impl<T, U> Into<U> for T where U: From<T>` you can also do this after implementing `From`: `let component: &mut Point = component.into();`

Answer (score 3):

The proper syntax is:

```
let component = <&mut Point>::from(component);
```

It's essentially the "turbofish" syntax without the leading `::`.